# ClassLoader getResourceAsStream returns null

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, classloader, inputstream

My project directory structure (in Eclipse):

```
MyProject/
    src/        --> "source directory" on Eclipse's classpath/buildpath
        com.me.myapp
            Driver
            myconfig.txt
```

In `Driver`, I have the following code:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("myconfig.txt");
        if(is == null)
            System.out.println("input stream is null");
        else
            System.out.println("input stream is NOT null :-)");
    }
}
```

When I run this I get the following console output:

```
input stream is null
```

**Why?** Have I placed `myconfig.txt` in an incorrect location? Am I using the ClassLoader API incorrectly? Something else?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If it's in the same package use

```
InputStream is = Driver.class.getResourceAsStream("myconfig.txt");
```

The way you have it

```
InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myconfig.txt");
```

It's looking for the file in the root of the classpath. You could use

```
InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/me/myapp/myconfig.txt");
```

The rules for searching are explained in the [javadoc of `ClassLoader#getResource(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) and the [javadoc of `Class#getResource(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 10):

If you are working with Maven, add the following lines under **BUILD** tag. You get this error when you are running the webapp on server but there is no reference to the resources on the server.

So, add this the following into your POM.xml and see the magic.

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>fileName.txt</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>fileName.wsdl</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Have Fun.!!!

Answer (score 0):

- **Instead of**-

  InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("myconfig.txt");
- **Use**-

  InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("com/me/myapp/myconfig.txt");
- **Note**:
  No need to provide source folder name (*src*) before package.