# class.getResourceAsStream() always returns null

Tags: java

I'm trying to copy the file "config.yml" into "plugins/AntiAura/config.yml".

However, I keep getting an NPE.

```
    [14:48:22 WARN]: java.lang.NullPointerException
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at a.e.a(Main.java:413)
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at a.e.d(Main.java:384)
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at a.e.onEnable(Main.java:637)
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at         org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(    JavaPlug
      in.java:321)
         [14:48:22 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(
JavaPluginLoader.java:335)
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(Si
mplePluginManager.java:405)
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugin
(CraftServer.java:355)
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.enablePlug
ins(CraftServer.java:315)
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.reload(Cra
ftServer.java:744)
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:534)
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(Rel
oadCommand.java:23)
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCo
mmandMap.java:141)
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCo
mmand(CraftServer.java:645)
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.dispatchSe
rverCommand(CraftServer.java:631)
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.DedicatedServer.aM(Dedic
atedServer.java:353)
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.DedicatedServer.z(Dedica
tedServer.java:317)
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.y(Minecr
aftServer.java:623)
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.run(Mine
craftServer.java:526)
    [14:48:22 WARN]:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    [14:48:22 INFO]: null ||
```

As you can see from the de-bug message at the bottom of the stacktrace, then the line I am using,

```
InputStream jarURL = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.yml");
```

is simply returning null.

I have tried both `InputStream jarURL = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.yml");` and `InputStream jarURL = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("config.yml");`. The file "config.yml" is definitely in the JAR file:

[image]
[image]

The solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035407/classloader-getresourceasstream-returns-null), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797162/getresourceasstream-is-always-returning-null) are things I am already doing, and do not solve the issue.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Unless the qualified name of your `Main` class is `plugins.AntiAura.Main`, both attempts are false. Prepending the name with a `/` implies that it is resolved as an absolute path, while omitting the `/` implies resolving relative to the `Class` on which you invoke the method. You may try `Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/plugins/AntiAura/config.yml")`…

Comment: Ah! So I need to put it in the OBFUSCATED package!! Well, that's another extra step for every new version release *sighs*. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Still looking for a more practical solution if anyone's got one.

Comment: That depends on your obfuscator, i.e. when the resource resided in the same package/folder before obfuscation, the tool should offer to adapt the resource path automatically. I know that `yguard` has such an option and would expect others to have a similar option as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have not config.yml in your classpath's root but in joehot200, so you need getResourceAsStream("/joehot200/config.yml")