# How to load resource from an absolute path?

Tags: java, tomcat, ff4j

I am using ff4j like this:

```
FF4J ff4j = new FF4J("config.xml");
```

Internally, FF4J calls `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.xml")`.

I want to be able to choose the config.xml location at deployment time (for example, `/etc` for linux).

How can I achieve that, without having to hardcode an absolute path? Is it possible to set the JVM / tomcat to look for the file in `/etc` for example? Or maybe there's another way to achieve what I want with FF4J?

Comment: Set it as an environment variable

Comment: Makes perfect sense, I don't know why I didn't think of that. This is the way to go and solves my issue. Just out of curiosity then, is it possible to set the JVM / tomcat to look for resources in specific folders ?

Comment: Not that I know of, but if anyone knows I'd be curious myself.

Comment: A resource gotten via getResource cannot stem from a file system path as shown. You could have different class paths per platform

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035407/classloader-getresourceasstream-returns-null and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java/1464366#1464366

Comment: set up environment variables or system variables.

Comment: Please note that the `FF4j` class also accept an `inputStream` as as direct constructor parameter @see https://github.com/ff4j/ff4j/blob/master/ff4j-core/src/main/java/org/ff4j/FF4j.java#L149, as such you can create some `FileInputStream` or your own or any inputstream you like.

Answer (score 0):

As creator of FF4j I would add a couple of solutions.

Before `1.8.9`

```
File configFile = new File("/tmp/ff4j.xml");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(configFile);
FF4j ff4j = new FF4j(fis);
```

Since `1.8.9`

```
 File configFile = new File("/tmp/ff4j.xml");
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(configFile);
 FF4j ff4j= new FF4j(new XmlParser(), fis);
```

As such you can now also import `Yaml` or `properties` files. (thinking about configMap in K8s world here). More samples [here](https://github.com/ff4j/ff4j/blob/master/ff4j-config-yaml/src/test/java/org/ff4j/parser/yaml/YamlParserTest.java)